# Merge query output to existing table. New rows should be added and for duplicate rows column name flag should be increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

Suppose I have table `a`

```
id company flag
1.  1001.    2
2.  1002.    1
3.  1003.    1
```

Want to merge below output to table `a`

```
1. 1001.   1
4. 1004.   1
3. 1003.   1
```

Output should be

```
1.  1001.    3
2.  1002.    1
3.  1003.    2
4.  1004.    1
```

Where `id` and `company` are same . Increment flag . Otherwise add new row. In SQL Server.

Comment: Have you had a look at `MERGE`?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(a.company, o.company) as company,
       coalesce(a.flag, 0) + coalesce(b.flag, 0) as flag
from a full join
     o
     on a.company = o.company;
```